# How to detect leak in non-heap memory in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

Our NodeJS application is facing memory leak issues for a while. Unlike other heap memory leak issues, I found there is a leak in non-heap using NewRelic APM tool. I'm using node 14.15.5 version.

I had gone through various articles to detect memory leaks in heap section but couldn't find one for non-heap. Due to this, GC metrics are poor which in turn increases avg. latency of the application. How do I find the non-heap memory leak? Does NodeJS upgrade helps?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure which line of code is causing memory leak. This thread is to understand the approach of diagnosing non-heap memory leak.